# How to track changes in development environment in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Our development team works on SQL Server and writes stored procedures for our product.

We need something like a version control system for those procedures or any other objects.

Sometimes I change a stored procedure, and someone else in my team changes it and I don't know any thing about it.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Did you try googling it?  There are tons of different ways easily found with simple google search or searcing here

Comment: There are LOTS of solutions and most of them tie in directly to your existing version control. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+version+control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it via code you could run this on a daily or hourly basis to get a list of all procs that were changed in the last day:

```
select * 
from sys.objects 
where datediff(dd, create_date, getdate()) < 1 
   or datediff(dd, modify_date, getdate() < 1) 
   and type = 'P';
```

or you could create a ddl trigger:

```
Create trigger prochanged On database
For create_procedure, alter_procedure,  drop procedure
as 
begin
    set nocount on

    Declare @data xml
    set @data = Eventdata()

    -- save @data to a table...
end
```

This will allow you to save all kinds of information every time a proc is created, changed or deleted.

Comment: Came here to advocate for the poor DBA's solution of the DDL trigger. One thing I'll note is that those triggering events are hierarchical. For example, the three that you listed can all be more succinctly expressed as `DDL_PROCEDURE_EVENTS` which is in turn only one facet of `DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS`. See `sys.trigger_event_types` for all of the event types and their lineage.